# Set include order of directory to last in gcc

Tags: c++, c, gcc, include, directory

Including the directory with -I command-line option in gcc appends the directory to the head of include directories.I want to add a directory to be searched after the system include directory.Is there any way to do this in gcc.

Comment: You could try `export INCLUDE_PATH=$INCLUDE_PATH:/your/dir`. Not sure whether gcc really uses `INCLUDE_PATH`, though.

Comment: Modified gcc-specs come to mind ...

Answer (score 1):

-nostdinc -I/first/include ... -I/last/include (note that you will need the normal include also)

Answer (score 0):

Gcc has a `-idirafter` flag that will add the include directory to the last searched directory (after every directory specified with `-I`)